How To set meta description for posts in wordpress using REST api
const WPAPI = require('wpapi');
const wp = new WPAPI({
endpoint: 'https://mywebsite.com/wp-json',
username: 'anyuser',
password: 'X0000',
});

const chaptersData = [
 { chapterNumber: '2', numImages: 61 },
 ];

 async function postChapters() {
 for (const chapter of chaptersData) {
    const title = `Title`;
    const description = `description`;
    const metadescription = `Metadescription`;
    let content = `<p>Para</p>`;

    try {
        const response = await wp.posts().create({
            title: title,
            content: content,
            status: 'publish',
            description: metadescription
        });
        console.log(`Success`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error`, error.message);
    }
}

}
postChapters();

i am using Node.js, Title, paras, and body images are setting perfect but I am not able to add description. Plz tell me how to add it.

Check if your WordPress site's REST API has support for updating post meta and if supported then update this code:
const WPAPI = require('wpapi');
const wp = new WPAPI({
    endpoint: 'https://mywebsite.com/wp-json',
    username: 'anyuser',
    password: 'X0000',
});

const chaptersData = [
    { chapterNumber: '2', numImages: 61 },
];

async function postChapters() {
    for (const chapter of chaptersData) {
        const title = `Title`;
        const description = `description`;
        const metadescription = `Metadescription`;
        let content = `<p>Para</p>`;

        try {
            const response = await wp.posts().create({
                title: title,
                content: content,
                status: 'publish',
                meta: {
                    '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc': metadescription
                },
            });
            console.log(`Success`);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error`, error.message);
        }
    }
}

postChapters();


What have you've actually changed to address the issue? Code-only answers are not good answers. Please explain

i updated this one:
meta: {
'_yoast_wpseo_metadesc': metadescription
},

Please [edit] the answer and add all details inside of it. Some clarification why this solves the issue is in order as well - If you have any source backing up this change, then please provide this as well

We need to setting up the meta description that is related to SEO.

if any other modifications you can suggest.

i just explain what i have modify into my code.

I've explicitly told you to [edit] the answer and provide all details inside of it
